# What are Adventurers League DMs empowered to do for encounter scaling purposes?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounter-design, dnd-adventurers-league

In D&D Adventurers League, I know that DMs can do the following for encounter scaling:

- Add or remove monsters from an encounter
- Adjust monster HP

because the modules usually have scaling instructions that include these things (and it doesn't say you have to use the formula in the module to determine which level to run at). But can DMs also adjust other monster stats? For instance, can a DM change e.g. the speed or AC of a monster?

Answer (score 6):

They are allowed to do as they see fit.  This is succinctly covered in the [D&D Adventurer's League Dungeon Master's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/AL_DMG_SKT.pdf):

> **Adjusting the Adventure**
>
> In any D&D Adventurers League adventure, you might see sidebars to help you make adjustments to the adventure, accommodating smaller or larger groups, or characters of higher or lower levels than the optimal party size. Most of the time, this information is used for combat encounters.
>   You can also adjust the adventure on the fly, beyond the guidelines given in the adventure, or make other changes as you see fit in order to insure your players have a good time.

Comment: And that is why I like AL. That the DM is empowered to control the flow of the game

Comment: It may be worth noting that regardless of changes made to an encounter, for *modules*, the DM is still restricted by the minimum and maximum XP listed in the back of each DDAL module. For hardcovers, there are no such limits.